# c++ enum as parameter in a function and calling the function in another file

Tags: c++, function, parameters, enums

I am making an engine in c++. Its nothing special yet and I am a beginner in c++ but I thought it would be a fun project to work on learn the skills I need later when I start working. I am making a function that takes user input and when that specific key is pressed it can execute the code you want like Input.GetKeyDown in unity. I have a problem and that is that I am trying to give an enum with all the keycodes for the keys as a parameter but it gives an error and I cant find a working sollution anywhere.
This is my code:

Functions.cpp

```
enum keyinputlist
{
 a = 97, b = 98, c = 99, d = 100, e = 101,
 f = 102, g = 103, h = 104, i = 105, j = 106, k = 107,
 l = 108, m = 109, n = 110, o = 111, p = 112, q = 113,
 r = 114, s = 115, t = 116, u = 117, v = 118,
 w = 119, x = 120, y = 121, z = 122
};

bool Functions::test(keyinputlist List)
{
  bool Success = CheckInput(List);
  return Success;
}
```

Functions.h

```
class Functions
{
 public:
   Functions();
   ~Functions();
   //Other public functions
   bool test(keyinputlist List);
};
```

Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
 Functions function;

 if (function.test(a) != 0)
 {
    std::cout << "It worked!" << std::endl;
    sleep_for(1.5s);
 }
 }
```

ErrorList:

```
E0020: identifier "a" is not found
E0020: identifier "keyinputlist" is not found
```

Comment: `keyinputlist` is missing `;` behind.

Comment: When I hover over the function is says "Decleration is incompatible with "function bool::test(<error-type> List" ".

Comment: You don't need typedefs for enums in C++.

Comment: put the declaration of the enum in the *.h file

Answer (score 4):

Someone answered this in a comment. Your problem is simple, the `enum` definition needs to go in `Functions.h`. You need to include `Functions.h` in both `Main.cpp` and `Functions.cpp`. Though because you aren't getting a lot more errors than you currently are I'm guessing you already do that.

In general, only code for non-template functions should go in a `.cpp` file. Type declarations and other similar things should probably live in a `.h` file.

The problem you're encountering is that because your `enum` is in a `.cpp` file and not included in `Main.cpp`, code in `Main.cpp` has no idea what you're talking about when you mention the enum type or any enum values. It hasn't seen any of that stuff, so it doesn't think it exists.

In general, the `enum` you have declared there seems like a bad idea. `'a'` is already 97 on almost all platforms supporting C++ (excluding IBM mainframes). Defining a character encoding with an enum is going to lead you to write a lot of extra code later because it's cumbersome.

Comment: And to avoid cluttering the global namespace you'd want `enum class` or to put `keyinputlist` into a namespace, and then `'a'` is far fewer characters.

Comment: @DanielH - agreed. But this person is a beginner. Small steps... ☺

Answer (score 0):

I have foudn the answer/problem.
I put in a instead of "class name"::a; that gave me the error and I put the enum in the header file and it works now.

Comment: You must've pasted incomplete code, because the code you pasted gave no indication that there was a class name involved at all. The `enum` looked like it was declared outside the scope of a class declaration.